# how to output only records with CNAME and A from AWS cli with jq

Tags: jq

I have the following query:

```
aws route53 list-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id ZJDMYXXXX --profile london | jq ".ResourceRecordSets[].Type"
```

which returns as expected

```
"A"
"A"
"A"
"A"
"A"
"A"
"A"
"A"
"A"
"A"
"CNAME"
"CNAME"
...
```

but how do I also return the `Name` from the output, which is something like:

```
{
    "ResourceRecordSets": [

        {
            "ResourceRecords": [
                {
                    "Value": "123.123.123.123"
                }
            ],
            "TTL": 21600,
            "Type": "A",
            "Name": "www.domain.tld."
        },
...
    ]
}
```

Any advice is much appreciated

Comment: Please follow the [mcve] guidelines as much as possible. In particular, it’s unclear what form you want the output to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return the `Name` and `Type` attributes of each entry.

```
   aws route53 .... | jq '.ResourceRecordSets[] | [.Name, .Type]'
```